# yum unable to find a specific package in private repo

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm, rhel8

I have a really weird problem. I've setup my private yum repo, it is serving the rpm just fine, EXCEPT one rpm.

Let's say I've build and copied over all of my rpms to my custom repo directory, something along the line:

```
postgresql-myStuff11-11.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-myStuff11-libs-11.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-myStuff11-devel.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-myStuff11-docs-11.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
...
```

All of them are there, I've clear my yum cache, rebuilt my yum repo using `createrepo --update` or even deleting the whole `repodata` folder and recreate it etc. But no matter what I do, it will not find my main package, when I run `yum search myStuff` (or myStuff11 etc).

It would only return EVERYTHING ELSE, except the main package.

```
Searching Packages:
==========================================================================================
Name Matched: myStuff11
==========================================================================================
postgresql-myStuff11-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for any PostgreSQL clients
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : postgresql-myStuff11-libs = 11.7-2.el8
...
```

At first, I thought maybe it was due to the `Name:` inside my spec file was using a defined variable, but even after I changed it to a string, it remained the exact same thing...

Question:

- How do you make `yum` to see the package `postgresql-myStuff11-11.7-2.el8.x86_64.rpm`?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: @djdomi Better...?

Comment: not yet at all, please read carefully the text i provided.

Comment: @djdomi I built a rpm package, put it in my yum repository, despite I clean and recreate all the cache and everything, but `yum` not seeing it. I want it to see the rpm that's in the yum repo. If you have better wording to my question, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: verify your repo index contains your new package after you updated it with createrepo. That index in just a text file, try grepping it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yeah that's the thing, the index file never contained my package, and that was from a fresh run of `createrpo`. See my answer, I had to run `createrepo` with the `-d` option.

Comment: sure, also notice that I gave that comment a day before you posted your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, I had to `createrepo` using the database (`-d`) flag. Here is what I did to be able to get it to work/show my packages.

1. Go to your YUM repo folder, ex: `cd /opt/myrepo`
2. `rm -rf repodata`, to wipe it clean
3. Recreate the repo but with database, `createrepo -v -d .`, (where `.` is `/opt/myrepo`)

Then on your remote machine, you could run `yum update --refresh` to pick up the new changes.

Without the `-d` flag, it was not able to list/display all of the packages I built, I have no idea why. The environment was in a RHEL 8 system, so this might (or might not) be a bug specific to `createrepo`.

```
createrepo --version
Version: 0.17.7 (Features: DeltaRPM LegacyWeakdeps )
```